# granting SELECT rights to tables without the user needing to qualify the owner on select

Tags: oracle, sqlalchemy, sql-grant

I have a number of tables, say `Metrics` and `Results`, some of many in a huge database that has lots of confidential information. I to set up security allowing a particular application to view data in those tables.  I don't need to modify them.  There about 200-300 tables involved in total, which carry information that is **NOT** confidential.

Like all the other tables, Metrics was created by the database owner/admin, let's say `dbo`.  If I connect as `dbo`, then I can simply do:

`select * from Metrics`.

Unfortunately, connecting as the owner of the database also means my connected user can see **all** tables, not just `Metrics` and can also update `Metrics`.

I would like to create a new user, `lowprivilege` and have the dba `GRANT SELECT METRICS TO lowprivilege`.

Unfortunately, that means I need to qualify the table owner when I connect as lowprivilege:

`select * from dbo.Metrics`.

How can a dba, under Oracle, grant SELECT to table without the receiver of the grant having to qualify the table owner?  And the low privilege user should have no privileges whatsoever beyond select in the chosen tables.

#### alternative 1 - a view:

`create view lowprivilege.Metrics as select * from dbo.Metrics`

That is a possibility, but I really need to keep the `*` wildcard as I don't know all the columns in Metrics.  The other issue is that I expect my view will break whenever dbo.Metrics gets rebuilt (which shouldn't happen very often).

#### alternative 2 - create synonym:

`create or replace lowprivilege.Metrics FOR dbo.Metrics`

Can the dba perform that and grant SELECT only using this?  Assume at least an Oracle 12 version.

#### alternative 3 - GRANT SELECT and switch schema:

`GRANT SELECT METRICS TO lowprivilege`

but, whenever `lowprivilege` connects it uses `alter session set current_schema=dbo`.  Note that this needs to be possible under SQLAlchemy /cx-Oracle.

Also, it would be great if the dba could close everything by just `DROP USER lowprivilege CASCADE`.

What are the best ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative #2 - create a synonym.  This is exactly what synonyms are for.

```
grant read on dbo.Metrics to lowprivilege;
create or replace synonym lowprivilege.Metrics FOR dbo.Metrics;
```

Notice the use of `GRANT READ` instead of `GRANT SELECT`.  A user with `SELECT` privilege can still lock the table.  `READ` privilege prevents that.

Comment: Txs.  I thought this would be the case, but was confused by their schema and user context explanation.  i.e. when the doc talks about create synomym privileges, I was thinking "I want the dba to deposit a ready-made read-only synonym on my low privilege guy", not grant anything else to my low privilege user.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid synonyms if the application can issue a command like this when it connects:

```
alter session set current_schema = HR;
```

Now the SQL parser will check the HR schema first for unqualified object names.

Rather than granting privileges directly to the `LOWPRIVILEGE` user, you might create a role and grant the privileges to that, and then grant that role to one or more application user accounts. This simplifies things when there are multiple users, and provides a level of self-documentation as the roles can have logical names.

```
grant read on metrics to readonly;

grant readonly to some_app_account;
```